# Database query failed: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

```
       SELECT  realestate.id,node.id,node.name
                from realestate,
                (SELECT
                    GROUP_CONCAT(parent.name_en ORDER BY parent.lft DESC) AS name,id
                  FROM
                    address AS node JOIN address AS parent
                    ON node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt  
                  WHERE node.lft >={$lft} and node.rgt <={$rgt}
                  GROUP BY node.name) as node
        INNER JOIN users ON id_user = users.id
        LEFT JOIN pic ON id_realestate = realestate.id
        WHERE node.id = realestate.address_id
```

I tried to modify it several times and this error message would not disappear "Database query failed: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous". is there any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Remind me,  why are we grabbing parent ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the subquery,

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(parent.name_en ORDER BY parent.lft DESC) AS name,
        id  -- <<== HERE (change to node.ID or parent.ID)
FROM    address AS node 
        JOIN address AS parent
           ON node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rg
```

You should specify on what table does the `ID` come from since both `node and parent` contains ID which causes ambiguity. It could be `node.ID` or `parent.ID`

Answer (score 2):

this is because you are using id in your concatenated query, so it's ambiguous, simply change to avoid the error

```
GROUP_CONCAT(parent.name_en ORDER BY parent.lft DESC) AS name,node.id --here you need to specify that is from node
```

Comment: +1 btw the sql comment is `--` not `//` :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(parent.name_en ORDER BY parent.lft DESC) AS name,id
```

with

```
GROUP_CONCAT(parent.name_en ORDER BY parent.lft DESC) AS name,node.id
```

you need to specify the alias of the table because mysql doesn't know what table to use to get the `id` column (assuming that both tables have a column named `id`).